# Discard all text between two specific words multiple times in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have some data in A1 which I would like to strip off of some text blocks that occur between two specific words.

The text is from some json data so it's a mixture of text, numbers and special characters. But in my case, once the two words are identified, it's okay to remove everything between these words without specifying any pick - choose.

My approach that I tried.

I replaced the two words with two different delimiters and then applied the SUBSTITUTE, SEARCH and MID functions but doesn't work.

The formula is quite large and untidy in my opinion and probably there is a better way to do this.

The link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10MpkGPzFyCPSZi7-qr7Ovi9vYevnaAVAn_rG0fsCrxU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Why not parrsing the json instead ? I will try it a bit later ...

Comment: I have to do it inside G sheets unfortunately.

Comment: It is not contrary!

Comment: but your data is not complete to parse !!

Comment: I understand that you have replace some terms by ⚽ and . It could be much more interessant to work on the original data. And faster.

Comment: I have updated the spreadsheet with original data. Please take a look.

Comment: Why don't you provide first the real data ? I would have saved a lot of time ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with xpath as defined inside the file

```
function getDataJSON(input,xpath){
  var data = JSON.parse(input)
  var liste = xpath.join().split(",")
  var result = []
  liste.forEach(function(elem){
    try{
      result.push(eval('data[0]'+elem.replace(/\//g,'\.')))
    }
    catch(e){result.push('')}
  })
  return([result])
}
```

[image]

Comment: More than I could have ever asked for!